# how to install iperf.exe on android based phone and running the utility using commands

Tags: android

I need to install iperf application on my android phone and want to run that application using the command prompt rather than the GUI interface available. Could anybody suggest me how to install `iperf.exe` on android based phone and running the utility using commands?

Comment: I don't know what `iperf.exe` is, but files ending in `.exe` are usually Windows programs, which will not run on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Android phones can't run .exe files as they are meant for Windows phones/PC.
Alternatively you can [try this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magicandroidapps.iperf&hl=en) for an Android device.